# REGEXR Validation of empty fields and match a pattern

Tags: asp.net, regex, validation

I have the following reg-ex that should be enough to validate if the field is empty or not and match the pattern that I need this reg-ex  is in a regular expression validator to validate a text box but if I leave the text box empty and hit the submit button it is saving the empty text box.

This is my reg-ex right here:

```
^(((?!00961)[0][0]|(?!00961)[+])([0-9]+))|((00)|(\+))961(\d|(7[0168])\d{6})|((7[1680]|03)\d{6})|(0[1-9]\d{6})$
```

Even a simple one like this one is not validating empty text:

```
^(\d{1,6}){1}$
```

Comment: Just a thought why not use requiredfieldvalidator ?

Comment: because i also need to match a certain pattern and there is only space for one control to fit next to the text box, also i kinda want to know why it isn't validating to see if the reg-ex is the problem or something i am missing

Answer (score 0):

In your click event are you calling Page.Validate or checking the IsValid property of the Page object?

```
protected void myButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if (Page.IsValid) {
        ....
    }
}
```

Comment: yeah i have used it but that is not the case because the control is validating the only case when it is not validating is when the text box is empty

Comment: Try adding the following to the beginning of your regex: ^\s*$|